# How to get cumulative sum based on a condition

Tags: r

I have a dataset with millions of values with 2 columns(ID, Amount). Amount is sorted in descending order. I need to get cumulative sum of amount based on a condition.

```
ID       Amount
101      40000
102      20000
103      15000
104      10000
......
```

For Example if there are 1000 rows I need the cumulative sum of first 1% i.e first 10 rows after sorting, then 4% (40), 15% (150), 35%(350) and below 50% (500).

How do I get this in R

Comment: Do you want a separate `cumsum` for each `ID` ?

Comment: @RafaelPereira I need the `cumsum` for entire base and not for each `ID` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
data <- 1:1000
n <- length(data)
quantile <- 0.01 # cumsum top 1%
cumsum(data[1:floor(n*quantile)])
```

Comment: Incase if I have duplicates in my dataset will `cumsum` add the duplicate also or will it skip it

Answer (score 0):

I would begin to ensure dataframe is sorted...,
I assume you only want the aggregated cumsum, not the detail

```
percentage=0.1
cumsum(df$Amount)[round(quantile(0:nrow(df),percentage))]
```